# How to add class to VueJS component slots?

Tags: components, vuejs2

I am currently refactoring an application and moving all form elements to one component called `Control` which will handle things like showing errors for a form control.

I currently have this part `class="input" :class="{ 'is-danger' : errors['description'] }"` left which is the same for every single component but slots can't be assigned any properties or attributes so what would be the way to solve the below issue and stop repeating that `:class` over and over?

**control.vue**

```
<template>
    <p class="control">
        <slot class="input" :class="{ 'error' : errors[model] }"></slot>

        <template v-if="errors[model]">
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
            <span class="help error">{{ errors[model][0] }}</span>
        </template>
    </p>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            model: String,
            errors: Object,
        }
    }
</script>
```

**usage - current**

```
<control model="description" :errors="errors">
    <input class="input" :class="{ 'is-danger' : errors['description'] }" type="text" v-model="item.description">
</control>
```

**usage - goal**

```
<control model="description" :errors="errors">
    <input type="text" v-model="item.description">
</control>
```

Comment: Maybe add the class binding to the p element and add CSS to apply it to the first child?

Comment: Not an option to do this since that would require a lot of changes to the CSS just to make this work.

Comment: `model="description" ` should be `:model="description" ` since you're passing it as a `props` to the `control component`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bind class to a slot in Vue.js 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42114188/bind-class-to-a-slot-in-vue-js-2)

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the slot in a div and apply styles or classes to the div instead.

Here the link to the accepted answer of a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47317694/2689455