# Bind class to a slot in Vue.js 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to create a reusable component for iterating over items, filtering them, and adding some classes to the slot (if the item is even, odd, first, last etc..)

Here's my reusable component:

```
<template>
  <ul :class="classes">
    <slot
      v-for="(item, index) in filteredItems"
      :item="item"
      :class="{
        'first': index == 0,
        'odd': !(index % 2),
        'even': index % 2,
        'last': index == (filteredItems.length - 1)
      }"
    >
    </slot>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['items', 'classes'],
  data() {
    return {
      filteredItems: this.items.filter(item => item.active)
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

And here's how I use it:

```
<component-list :classes="'some-class'" :items="category.products">
  <template scope="props">
    <product :product="props.item"></product>
  </template>
<component-list>
```

Everything works as expected, but it doesn't add classes to the element put inside .

Am I doing anything wrong? Is it even technically possible in Vue.js 2 to do something like this?

Thanks for any help or suggestion!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With `vuejs2` styling from slots has been removed as stated [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Slots):

> Content inserted via named  no longer preserves the slot attribute. Use a wrapper element to style them, or for advanced use cases, modify the inserted content programmatically using render functions.

So simplest thing as suggested will be to use a wrapper element as following:

```
<template>
  <ul :class="classes">
    <slot>
      <div
      v-for="(item, index) in filteredItems"
      :item="item"
      :class="{
        'first': index == 0,
        'odd': !(index % 2),
        'even': index % 2,
        'last': index == (filteredItems.length - 1)
      }"
    >
    </div>
    </slot>
  </ul>
</template>
```

Comment: Could you please provide a simple example or elaborate the ```modify the inserted content programmatically using render functions``` part? Thanks!

Comment: @MatúšČongrády [here is more info about render functions](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html)

Answer (score 9):

I have another way can get your aim, but not use `render`, still use `slot`.

The reusable component:

```
<template>
  <ul :class="classes">
    <slot
      v-for="(item, index) in filteredItems"
      :item="item"
      :_class="{
        'first': index == 0,
        'odd': !(index % 2),
        'even': index % 2,
        'last': index == (filteredItems.length - 1)
      }"
    >
    </slot>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['items', 'classes'],
  data() {
    return {
      filteredItems: this.items.filter(item => item.active)
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

**use `_class` to `class` keyword**, so `Vue.js` will let `_class` as the common property.

Then in your use:

```
<component-list :classes="'some-class'" :items="category.products">
  <template scope="{ item, _class }">
    <product :product="item" :class="_class"></product>
  </template>
<component-list>
```

By the scope property, your can still get `_class` from slot.

After all, use `render` may be more conciseness. :)

Answer (score 1):

In your child component don't use the slot tag, just bind the slot data to a normal element.

For example say I have a component called modal. In my parent I have this:

```
<modal>
    <h1 slot="title">My modal title</h1>
</modal>
```

So with normal slot use my child component would have the following markup:

```
<slot name="title" class="this-class-will-not-get-added"></slot>
```

But that class will not get added.

So instead we can do this:

```
<h1 class="this-class-will-get-added">{{this.$slots.title['0'].children['0'].text}}</h1>
```