# Vue dynamic class binding with computed props

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, computed-properties

I am trying to bind a class from a parent component to a child component via a computed switch case to an slot.
Parent:

```html
<template>
  <mcTooltip :elementType="'text'"><p>Test</p></mcTooltip>
</template>

<script>
import mcTooltip from '@/components/mcTooltip/index.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    mcTooltip
  }
};
</script>
```

Child:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <slot :class="[elementClass]" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    elementType: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      // must have one of these elements
      validator: (value) => {
        return ['text', 'icon', 'button'].includes(value);
      }
    }
  },

  data() {
    return {};
  },

  computed: {
    elementClass: () => {
      // return this.elementType ? 'tooltip--text' : 'tooltip--text';
      // calls prop value for verification
      switch (this.elementType) {
        case 'text':
          return 'tooltip--text';
        case 'icon':
          return 'tooltip--icon';
        case 'button':
          return 'tooltip--button';
        default:
          return 'tooltip--text';
      }
    }
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.tooltip--text {
  text-decoration: underline dotted;
  cursor: pointer;

  &:hover {
    background: $gray_220;
  }
}
</style>
```

Whatever I try I dont seem to make it work in any way. Thats my latest attempt. The vue devtools say to my computed prop "(error during evaluation)".

Comment: Try the computed property without an arrow function. You can also replace the switch with an Object - `{text: 'tooltip--text', icon: 'tooltip--icon', button: 'tooltip--button'}[this.elementType] || 'tooltip--text'`

Comment: You typically can't set a class (or any other attributes) on the `<slot>` element. See [Bind class to a slot in Vue.js 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42114188/bind-class-to-a-slot-in-vue-js-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, the way I did it is as following:

```
  <div
    v-show="showTooltip"
    ref="mcTooltipChild"
    :class="['tooltip__' + elementType]"
  ></div>

    elementType: {
      type: String,
      default: 'small',
    },
```