# Styling Vue Slot

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Is there any way to style a slot in a Vue component?

```
<slot style="position: absolute"></slot>
```

and

```
<slot class="slot"></slot>
```

do not work.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Wrap the slot in a `<div>` and style the `<div>` instead:

```
<div style="...">
  <slot></slot>
</div>
```

If you really need to style the slot element, you can use CSS selectors like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <slot></slot>
</div>
```

```
.wrapper > * {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, that solution wouldn't work if more than one element is passed into the slot.

Comment: `.wrapper > *` will target every slot element. If you need to target only a specific slot element, you can use `.wrapper > *:nth-child(2)` or `.wrapper > .child`. What specifically are you trying to do? Do you want to be able to bind a dynamic `style` of each slot element, or will using external CSS suffice?

Comment: Wrapping with a div, or some other element, can and often does break the content flow.... You suddenly have a random <div> where it shouldn't be, and it may not have the necessary styling to behave like the slots contents. And unfortunately `display: contents` isn't well supported.

Comment: You could use the `:deep(selector)` overriding the scoped styling, but I don't know if it's recommended.

Answer (score 9):

- You can use :slotted Selector:

```css
:slotted(.classInsideSlot) { 
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can pass a class from the parent like so:

In the component template:

```
<slot name="quoteText"></slot>
```

And when passing to the slot:

```
<p slot="quoteText" class="mb-md-100">Text</p>
```

Comment: `slot` attributes are deprecated for vue3

Answer (score 1):

I found such a way out.

```
    computed: {
        isAppBoxSlotActive() {
            return Boolean(this.$slots['app-box']);
        }
    },

    <div v-if="isAppBoxActive"
         :class="$style['app-box']">
        <slot name="app-box">...</slot>
    </div>
```

Comment: $slots['app-box'] did not work for me 
I had to change to $slots.appBox using vue 3

Answer (score 0):

You can also use deep selectors to style slotted content...

https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors

```
<style scoped>
.a >>> .b { /* ... */ }
</style>

//or 

<style scoped>
.a::v-deep .b { /* ... */ }
</style>
```