# Is there a way to contextually style elements in a parent vue component, using a child?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

This is best explained with an example:
Here is the template of a  reusable `sidebar.vue` component (uses vuetify though I don't think that's relevant to this question - also I've had to remove the template tags themselves as they screw with the rendering on stack overflow):

```
<v-navigation-drawer 
    right clipped fixed
    :width="navBarWidth"
    v-on="$listeners" v-bind="$attrs">
    <v-card flat>
        <v-form>
            <v-card-title class="stages-heading">
                {{ heading }}
            </v-card-title>
            <slot></slot>
        </v-form>
    </v-card>
</v-navigation-drawer>
```

Here an example section of a parent vue component which uses this sidebar:

```
<sidebar>
    <v-card-title class="stages-subheading">Stage name</v-card-title>
</sidebar>
```

What I want to achieve, is that if I put an element into an instance of the sidebar, just as `v-card-title` is being placed within an instance of the sidebar in the 2nd box above, the child applies a style to that element due to it being inside its tags. So, where above I have to use `class="stages-subheading"` every time I want a `v-card-title` within my parent components, I would like not to have to do this every time, but instead, have my sidebar component do this for me.

This is a simple example possibly, but I need to understand the concept of how to do this so I can take it further.

I've tried googling everything I can think of to no avail, so would greatly appreciate any help :)

Comment: CSS rules are of the forms of an identity, a sibling relationship, or a descendent relationship.  As far as I know, CSS does not support ancestor relationship rules.

Comment: I think this post answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47317479/styling-vue-slot

Comment: just curious, can you post up ur css section inside sidebar and v-card-title, please?

Comment: Thanks for the replies everyone, I believe to solve this specific problem sebasaenz's post  is the solution - i need to make use of CSS selectors. It seems defining this in the child.vue isn't possible, but rather in global css? I'll post the CSS below as Kick Buttowski asked...

Comment: The v-card title style:

    .stages-subheading {
    font-family: $font-family-roboto-bold !important;
    font-size: 17px !important;
    color: black;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}


the sidebar component is just given access to our global css styles, the stages-heading style class isn't relevant here.